# Send Multiple Terminal Commands in Gnome Terminals With Subprocess

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, subprocess

So I am currently trying to run two different gnome-terminal windows in Ubuntu that I can send individual commands to after they are initially open.

```
def ssh_command(cmd):

ssh_terminal_1 = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'bash', '-c', cmd], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
ssh_terminal_2 = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'bash', '-c', cmd], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Activate the conda environment for our multilateration server
spyder_activate('conda activate flyhound')

time.sleep(10)

ssh_terminal_1.stdin.flush()
ssh_terminal_2.stdin.flush()

ssh_terminal_1.stdin.write(b'cd srsRAN22.04/build')
ssh_terminal_1.stdin.flush()
ssh_terminal_2.stdin.write(b'cd srsRAN22.04/build')
ssh_terminal_2.stdin.flush()

ssh_terminal_1.stdin.write(b'sudo ./srsepc/src/srsepc ../srsepc/epc.conf.example --hss.db_file=../srsepc/user_db_unknown.csv.example\n')
ssh_terminal_1.stdin.flush()

ssh_terminal_2.stdin.write(b'bladeRF-cli -l /home/administrator/Downloads/hostedxA5-latest.rbf\n')
ssh_terminal_2.stdin.flush()
ssh_terminal_2.stdin.write(b'bladeRF-cli -f /home/administrator/Downloads/bladeRF_fw_v2.4.0.img\n')
ssh_terminal_2.stdin.flush()
ssh_terminal_2.stdin.write(b'sudo ./srsenb/src/srsenb ../srsenb/enb.conf.example --enb_files.sib_config=../srsenb/sib.conf.example --e nb.n_prb=50 --enb_files.rr_config=../srsenb/rr.conf.example\n')
```

However when I start the original subprocess command the terminals open up fine with the command given during the function call but all the following commands don't work and I get a broken pipe error errno 32. While I try to run these commands I also need to keep previous terminal open that looks like this below

```
def access_command(cmd):

while True:
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print(output.strip())  
        if b"f0:9e:4a:5f:a4:5b" and b"handshake" in output:
            ssh_command("sshpass -p earth ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no administrator@ipaddress; clear; screen")
```

I am really not sure how I can send multiple commands to the ssh terminals after they ssh into that ip address. I am very new to subprocess and sending commands to terminals via python so any help would be amazing on this!!

Comment: I'm not sure it is easy or feasible to do what you want to do. I assume the launch of the spyder stuff has to be located in the exact sequence you have it, and can only be done once? The problem is once you launch a terminal, it takes its input from the console, not from the pipe. You lose communication therefore with the terminal once it launches.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in the comments, your pipe goes to `gnome-terminal` and neither to `ssh` nor to `bash`. `gnome-terminal` is not listening to stdin but is only listening to the user at the console. Here is what you do.

1. Make a FIFO (named pipe) -- `os.mkfifo` -- for each terminal, give it a name that won't collide with any other file (such as put your process ID in it).
2. Issue the command `gnome-terminal -- bash -c ssh <options> < <fifo name>` for each terminal. Do not make this a `Popen` call, use `os.system` or something like that.
3. Do your spydy magic (`anaconda`).
4. Open the FIFO as a file
5. Write your commands to the open file; they will be executed by the `bash` process in the `ssh` connection. You will probably have to flush, unless there is a way to open it in line-buffered mode.
6. When you want to close the terminal, close the file.

What this accomplishes is that we move the pipe from `gnome-terminal` to `ssh` and hence across the connection to `bash`. We feed it on one end and it comes out and gets digested by the shell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What I ended up doing was setting up multiple commands from the initial popen command and setting the continuously running command as the last one to run and setting that within a while loop to actually keep the terminal running. Not sure if that is the most optimal way but thats what i got!